# Vertical plane detection issue in ARCore - SceneView

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneview

Scenario:
I'm developing application to detect the surface for measurement, I'm using ARCore SDK for this purpose which works perfectly fine for `HORIZONTAL VIEW` but the issue is on vertical analyzing part as it didn't show any dots to detect the surface.

```
 sceneView = findViewById<ARSceneView?>(R.id.sceneView).apply {
            planeRenderer.isEnabled = true
            configureSession { session, config ->
                config.depthMode = when (session.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC)) {
                    true -> {Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC
                    }
                    else -> Config.DepthMode.DISABLED


                }


               config.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL
               config.depthMode = Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC
               config.instantPlacementMode = Config.InstantPlacementMode.LOCAL_Y_UP
                config.lightEstimationMode = Config.LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR
               // config.updateMode=Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE


            }

  
            onSessionUpdated = { _, frame ->
                if (anchorNode == null) {
                    frame.getUpdatedPlanes()
                        .firstOrNull { it.type == Plane.Type.VERTICAL }
                        ?.let { plane ->

                            //   addAnchorNode(plane.createAnchor(plane.centerPose))
                        }
                }
            }

            onTrackingFailureChanged = { reason ->
                this@MainActivity.trackingFailureReason = reason
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$reason", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            onSessionFailed={ fail->
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
            onSessionUpdated={
                session, frame ->

               // Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
```

Above code works fine on Horizontal plane but when we change the  configureSession to Vertical it didn't detect any vertical plane for any vertical texture.

**Already tried**

> config.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL

Comment: It's preferable to start a question with, well, a question. Describe your problem at a high level so that people know immediately whether they can help, without having to look at the code.